# Apache POI - DROP DOWN value removing '00000' from data

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I am building dynamic drop down through java code and it is working perfectly fine.
    The code I am running is:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Data Validation");
XSSFDataValidationHelper dvHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
XSSFDataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = (XSSFDataValidationConstraint)
dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"0000011", "0000021", "0000031"});
CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0, 0, 0, 0);
XSSFDataValidation validation = (XSSFDataValidation)dvHelper.createValidation(
dvConstraint, addressList);
validation.setShowErrorBox(true);
validation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
sheet.addValidationData(validation);
```

Drop down are coming properly but when I select any one of the value from drop-down `00000` are automatically removed and only 11 is getting displayed, but I want value to be `0000011` to be selected from drop down.

drop value is showing as `0000011` but after selection it display `11`. Might be if we can change cell type to text it will help or some other way but how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this on my own after lot of research. so I thought to post answer to help others.

```
// setting cell type as string to avoid removing 00000 from drop down
CellStyle textStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
textStyle.setDataFormat((short)BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat("text")); 
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);
```

Comment: style.setDataFormat(HSSFDataFormat.getBuiltinFormat("@"));.//this also works